# Query Data From Inner Child (Deep Query)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hi, i have a firebase database structure as in image.

I would like to query data which contain`"statuskirim"= "Not Shipped"` which is located deep inside Order child.

I have first child (Order), 2nd child (081000, 0567743251. e.t.c),  3rd child- inside each 2nd child ( will be 1, 2, 3 and so on).

In each 3rd child there's a node called `"statuskirim"` which i would like to query.

previously i don't use 3rd child (which is 1,2,3 e.t.c).

My query with this code was succesful :

```
ordersRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order")
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminOrders> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminOrders>()      .setQuery(ordersRef.orderByChild("statuskirim").equalTo("Shipped"),AdminOrders.class)
.build();
```

But i don't have idea how to queries after i added the 3rd child.

i guess i should add a 2nd child in `"ordersRef"`,  i,e

```
ordersRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order").child("0810000")
```

It's work for one 2nd child which is ("0810000" , but how i add all 2nd child   (in case a have a lot of 2nd child)

edited code as Peter Hadad Sugegsted :

```
DatabaseReference reference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String key = datas.getKey();

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminOrders> options = new 
FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminOrders>()    .setQuery(ordersRef.orderbyChild(key).orderByChild("statuskirim").equalTo("Shipped"),AdminOrders.class)
```

.build();

... (so on ending tag display data e,t.c)  but then the result only shown the last data of 2nd child not all data

Comment: can you show the structure of database then I will help you to make a query?

Comment: in the image above ? could you saw the image link? i tried to add image but i's converted to link

Comment: do you want to access all data of 2 child

Comment: yes all data of 2nd child (key1, key2,key3 and so on)

Comment: ok SO you have to add you 2nd child in database reference then you can get all data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String key = datas.getKey();

    reference.child(key).orderByChild("statuskirim").equalTo("Shipped").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String statuskirim = ds.child("statuskirim").getValue().toString();
      }
    }
      @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
  });

  }
}
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

Here, in this case `getKey()` will retrieve the 2nd child, then you can use it inside a `child()` and then you will be able to use `orderByChild()` query.

Though, it is probably better to optimize the database, and not add more nested children.

Comment: ok  wil try it, i seeking how to use all data  of 2nd child , so its will looping until all 2ndchild data read isn't , just like For-Next statement in (visualBasic)

Comment: Yes it will loop and u can get the data inside the 3rd child

Comment: Peter Haddad : I modified it a bit since i use Recycler option but then the result only showing the result of first 2nd child  here the code i modified.

Comment: code i edit above in my question.  i mean only showing the result from the last data of 2nd child node

Comment: I found a solution, i put all 2ndchild key into.spinner and then user chose from spinner to query 3rd child.data